# What are the 6 characters at the end of an IE 10's User Agent string?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, touch, user-agent

What are the 6 characters at the end of an IE 10's User Agent string?
Here are some samples:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Touch; MATPJS)"
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0; Touch; ASU2JS)"
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0; Touch; MALNJS)"
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Touch; MDDCJS)"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the manufacturer's shortcode.

See: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/learn/unknown-user-agent-fragments/